# Marquee won't scroll when using short text

Tags: android, text, textview, marquee, short

I want to use the marquee property for short texts. I wrote this code:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/MarqueeText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:paddingLeft="15dip"
        android:paddingRight="15dip"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Hello" >
```

and it doesn't work. But when I changed the text as "hello hello hello hello hello etc." (long text) it works. How can I use marquee for short texts?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `fill_parent` for your `layout_width`, use a set width. The marquee is enabled when the characters are longer than the View's width.

Comment: This doesn't have any effect for me.