# Is the Marquee a Text-length-dependent?

Tags: android, marquee

I have set a `textView` to be a `marquee`, this `textView` gets assigned to values dynamically during the run-time and its value could be sometime a single character or a long sequence of characters. What I realized is, some times the marquee works and sometimes do not.

Is the `marquee` a length-dependent? if yes, how can I change the restriction or the limitation to a specific character length?

***Update***

I forgot to mention that the `textView` is always selected to have the focus.

Comment: It works only when the TextView is selected. Have you checked that?

Comment: it is selected, though surprisingly, sometime work and sometimes dont

Comment: It is lenght-dependent in the sense that it only starts when the text is longer than the available space. So when you have 1 char it won't start, but if you have 100 chars and only 50 available spaces it will start. Also, keep in mind that it only works on single line textview.

Comment: @DavidCorsalini thank you, i have just referred to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549434/marquee-wont-scroll-when-using-short-text   and it is exactly what you suggested